How to POST request to windy.com for bounding box region
I was reviewing the API for windy.com and found that you can only retrieve weather information for a specific latitude/longitude but I was wondering if there is a way to retrieve information for a set of coordinates?
{
    "lat": [min_lat, max_lat],
    "lon": [min_lon, max_lon],
    "model": "desired_model",
    "parameters": ["desired_parameter_1", "desired_parameter_2", ...],
    "levels": ["optionally_desired_gh_level_1", ...],
    "key": "your_API_key"
}

